# How to enable c++11 in make command in kali linux

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, installation

I am installing codeblocks in kali linux using source files. but when I issue make command I got the following error

```
usr/include/c++/6/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
```

I googled for this error and got the following solution of using this in my Makefile and recompile

```
CXX=clang++
CXXFLAGS=-g -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic
BIN=prog

SRC=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ=$(SRC:%.cpp=%.o)

all: $(OBJ)
        $(CXX) -o $(BIN) $^

%.o: %.c
        $(CXX) $@ -c $<

clean:
        rm -f *.o
        rm $(BIN)
```

but this also don't works. I am new to linux and have no idea how to enable c++11 mode in gcc.

Comment: I don't see you using `CXXFLAGS` anywhere. That's the key here.

Comment: Clearly you don't understand your own makefile and are trying to use GNU Make before
taking the trouble to learn basically how it works. Here is [a fairly good beginner's
tutorial about GCC and GNU Make](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html).
For authoritative documentation, here is the [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#toc-An-Introduction-to-Makefiles)

Answer (score 1):

The `CXXFLAGS` aren't being used.  You can modify the all rule to

```
all: $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(BIN) $^
```

Comment: hi, I use this fix, but still getting the same error in terminal